# Ngfor does not change when arrray is override

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I have implemented a search by 'Cliente ID' which not necessarily has to be the ones which appears by default. Nonetheless, it never changes.

This is my component method

```
 cliente: Cliente[];

 barrabusqueda()
  {
  if (this.selected = 1) {
    var getSelectedValue = parseInt((document.getElementById("idenvio")as HTMLInputElement).value);
    this.conexion.getClientePorId(getSelectedValue).subscribe(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
      Object.keys(this.cliente).forEach(key => {
        console.table(key);
        console.table(this.cliente[key]);
      });
      this.cchangeDetection.detectChanges();
      });
    
  }
   
  }
```

I have checked console logs and it can be seen that log that the information is coming OK.

This is my service

```
    const path = `${this.api}/clientes/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(path).pipe
    (
      catchError(e =>{
        console.error(e.error.Mensaje);
        Swal.fire('Error al buscar el cliente', e.error.Mensaje, 'error');
        return throwError(e);
      })
      
    )};
```

And this is my html

```
div class="col" id="tabla">
  <li >
    <table class="table table-border">
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-danger"> 
          <th scope="col">Id Cliente</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre del Cliente</th>
          <th scope="col">CIF / NIF</th>
          <th scope="col">Dirección de Facturación</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
        <tr class="table-danger" *ngFor = "let cliente of clientes | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: pages}">
          <td class="table-danger">{{cliente.idCliente}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger" >{{cliente.nombreCliente}} </td>
          <td class="table-danger" >{{cliente.cifnif}} </td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{cliente.direccionFacturacion}}</td>
         
        </tr>
     
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </li>
</div>
```

And interface idCliente in case you need

```
export interface Cliente
{
    idCliente: number;
    cifnif: string;
    direccionFacturacion: string;
    nombreCliente: string;
    
  
}
```

It gives always the same results even it receives the object correctly.

Comment: I attach you the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/yfmZcVR

Comment: pls reproduce your issue on the https://stackblitz.com/ if possible, this is hard to debug for you

Comment: i cannt because i am consulting a local database :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really get the data. According to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wjZ0.jpg) that you shared, it looks like there is an error block and you are setting clients in the success block. Try to console log the response and see if data is indeed available.

Comment: Hi, there is an error but it does not affect, it is refering to a modal which is not selected, everthing but that works ok in spile of existing the error

Comment: Can you try console logging the response and see what you get?

Comment: This it what _this.cliente_ values `idCliente clientes.component.ts:95:16 2 clientes.component.ts:96:16 
direccionFacturacion clientes.component.ts:95:16 
Calle FALSA 123 1ºA clientes.component.ts:96:16
 cifnif clientes.component.ts:95:16 
 41727883H clientes.component.ts:96:16
 nombreCliente clientes.component.ts:95:16
 Alonso Marinstfhg clientes.component.ts:96:16`

Comment: I believe you are supposed to set your response to clientes variable instead of cliente since you are looping through the clientes variable in *ngFor.

Comment: I changed this method  cliente : Clientes[] and nothing changes                                 ` barrabusqueda()
  {
  if (this.selected = 1) {
    var getSelectedValue = parseInt((document.getElementById("idenvio")as HTMLInputElement).value);
    this.conexion.getClientePorId(getSelectedValue).subscribe(data => {
       this.clientes = data;
      console.log("LLENO");
       Object.keys(this.clientes).forEach(key => {
        console.table(key);
        console.table(this.clientes[key]);
      });
      this.cchangeDetection.detectChanges();
      });
      
  }`

Comment: Do you mind creating a temp repo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and sharing, maybe I can be able to help if I can see the actual code.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get my api info from it? It is not json inside a component

Comment: You can set up a whole project like you have now.